# REST обновление сущности в JPA. PUT или PATCH?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Скажите, пожалуйста какой маппинг надо выбирать в контроллере @PutMapping или @PatchMapping при редактировании в ресте какой-то сущности? Там как идет, в базе данных запись перетрется полностью, но с теми же значениями и какими-то новыми или в бд будут обновлены только новые значения?

Comment: https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: На вкус и цвет... Дело в том, что в [оригинальном виде](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) про это вообще ничего не сказано. Главное - чтобы у тебя в приложении было логическая согласованность и единообразие.